# Troubleshooting DC motor no load current with power supply

Tags: dc-motor

I am trying to characterize a DC motor I harvested from a drill. I am using a power supply (0-30V, 0-5A) and am trying to measure no load current. With my power supply set to 18V (voltage controlled) it won't start unless I help it (give it a twist). This is the case no matter where I set my voltage and current. Once I get it turning, the voltage on my power supply reads below 2V and the motor speed changes only when I change the current limit. Why would this be? Voltage should control speed, no?

Comment: Check the brushes. This sounds as if they are down to nothing and the motor has serious ringfire because of that. That causes heavy overcurrent.

Comment: @Janka That's a good point.  My answer below assumed the motor was in working condition when harvested from the drill, but if not it could certainly be an issue with worn brushes.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. What use conditions damage the brushes like that?

Answer (score 1):

During startup there's no back EMF to limit the current, so your supply is likely going into current limit.  In general, motors need high current to get started.

Once the motor has started the back EMF "fights" the supply and the current drops.

[image]

eb is the back EMF in the equivalent circuit shown, and it's equal to the back EMF constant times the angular motor speed.  So at no load there's no eb to work against the source, and the current is only limited by the winding resistance Ra and the inductance La.

The reason for the voltage on your supply going to 2V is again the supply is hitting its current limit.  When you raise the current limit it allows the supply voltage to increase, increasing the motor speed.

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick reply.  What kind of load would you recommend for sufficient start-up eb in this case?